# Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(int) is not yet implemented

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I am trying to configure dbcp2 with postgres 9.1

When I run my app, it throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(int) is not yet implemented.)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:575)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:639)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:664)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:704)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:195)
    at com.springinpractice.ch02.service.impl.ContactServiceImpl.getContact(ContactServiceImpl.java:64)
    at com.springinpractice.ch02.ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:16)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(int) is not yet implemented.)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2152)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1903)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(int) is not yet implemented.
    at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:753)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.isValid(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:109)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(Jdbc4Connection.java:21)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:914)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:227)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:303)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2165)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2148)
    ... 11 more
```

Here is my maven POM:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Test Artifacts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For JDBC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That method is implemented in the current driver version. You must be using an old PgJDBC. Upgrade. It's fully backward compatible. (You should've specified your PgJDBC version in the question).

Separately, though, relying on connection "validation" is usually a bad idea. It's just a way of trying to imperfectly hide a race condition. Simply grab the connection and use it. If there's a problem with it, your application should trap the resulting exception, check the `SQLSTATE` to see if it's a connection related error, and retry with a new connection.

Comment: Thanks Craig. Once I changed the driver to "9.3-1102-jdbc41", it works. I thought the version of driver must match the version of database I am using (9.1). Apparently driver with version 9.3 works on old database too.

Comment: wrong jar -https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql. Right jar - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql

Answer (score 17):

Replace your postgresql with below entry in pom.xml. My Postgress version was postgresql-9.3.10-3.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 11):

Craig has right. The root cause is postgresql group id changed to org.postgresql and the old group doesn't get the updates. You should refresh your dependency node i.e.:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

according to the current latest version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/

Answer (score 2):

Solution:
Set a validation query for parameter "validationQuery".

E.g for bean:
  property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"

This validation query is run against the connection before returning it. So have a valid query, above is a dummy one.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this dependency:
this will solve this problem

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the POM.xml version to

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, if you are using SSL, the jdbc URL should be following format

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://hostName:5432/db?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

This ticket helped me to solve the issue: [Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection.getEncoding()Lorg/postgresql/core/Encoding;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181574/caused-by-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-postgresql-core-baseconnection-geten)

Basically, you need to exclude PostGIS stubs:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.3</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
         <artifactId>postgis-stubs</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```