# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection.getEncoding()Lorg/postgresql/core/Encoding;

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc

I am configure PostgreSQL,Hibernate in spring mvc . i have getting following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection.getEncoding()Lorg/postgresql/core/Encoding;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection.getEncoding()Lorg/postgresql/core/Encoding;
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getString(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1889)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.initSequences(DatabaseMetadata.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.<init>(DatabaseMetadata.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.<init>(DatabaseMetadata.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't completly explain the context you're getting the exception, but I'llm make a few assumptions.

The error happens when you're using a postgres 8 driver, against a postgres 9 DB. A common case is that it is pulled in as a transitive dependency via whatever build system you're using. To make even more assumptions, the very common case is that an older driver is included when adding postgis dep e.g. via maven. The solution is to exclude the dep, e.g. like

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.3</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
         <artifactId>postgis-stubs</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

anyways, it could be a different dependency, or a different build system, but the gist of the answer should apply, find out what brings the erroneus dep to your classpath, and exclude it

Comment: Man, you have saved me from this dam

`    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection.getPreferQueryMode()Lorg/postgresql/jdbc/PreferQueryMode`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: FWIW, excluding `postgresql:postgresql` did it for me. That's a dependency of `postgis-stubs` too, so I'm not saying the above solution doesn't work. But no need to exclude more than needed. (Of course make sure a _right_ version of the driver _is_ in your dependencies.)