# Does Tomcat DBCP support JDBC4 isValid() API?

Tags: tomcat, apache-commons-dbcp, jdbc-pool

Is there any Tomcat DBCP version that supports JDBC4 `isValid()` API? Or do I have to always supply a `validationQuery` even for JDBC4-compliant drivers?

Answer (score -1):

[`commons-dbcp`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) does support JDBC4:

> - DBCP 2 compiles and runs under Java 7 only (JDBC 4.1)
> - DBCP 1.4 compiles and runs under Java 6 only (JDBC 4)

Support for`isValid` also [must be implemented by the DB driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594279/method-org-postgresql-jdbc4-jdbc4connection-isvalidint-is-not-yet-implemented), however I presume that once a driver claims to be compatible with jdbc4, it should support it.

Comment: The question referred to Tomcat DBCP, not commons-dbcp