# java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(int) is not yet implemented. in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, postgresql, docker, spring-boot, microservices

I am developing `Spring Boot Microservices` example. In this example, I used `config-server` and `licensing-service` and deployed successfully on `docker`. When I call the REST endpoint : http://localhost:8080/v1/organizations/1/licenses, I got the below error.

To solve this error, I went through many links already, but none of the solutions worked for me yet. The refer links :

I have taken actual code reference from : https://github.com/carnellj/spmia-chapter3

1. [Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(int) is not yet implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594279/method-org-postgresql-jdbc4-jdbc4connection-isvalidint-is-not-yet-implemented)
2. https://sbforge.org/jira/browse/BITMAG-508

**Error:**

```
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(int) is not yet implemented.
licensingservice_1  |   at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:753) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.isValid(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:120) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(Jdbc4Connection.java:21) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
licensingservice_1  |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkDriverSupport(PoolBase.java:445) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
licensingservice_1  |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:412) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
licensingservice_1  |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:370) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
licensingservice_1  |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
licensingservice_1  |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
licensingservice_1  |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
licensingservice_1  |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
licensingservice_1  |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
licensingservice_1  |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d239cd6.getConnection(<generated>) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1985) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1915) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1893) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:938) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:392) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1490) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.9.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.9.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.9.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.9.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.9.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.9.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.9.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.9.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
licensingservice_1  |   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.9.RELEASE]
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>Finchley.SR1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

instead. It is the latest version from the maven repository. Tried it locally and it cleared out the error.